# NullPointerException on Apache Server Servlet using JPA

Tags: java, servlets, jpa

Im trying to display contents of table (test_dept) which is in SQLSERVER
I have created a connection profile also.
I have written a Servlet like below... But Im getting this error.

[image]

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
//import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/ServletClient")
public class ServletClient extends HttpServlet
{
  @PersistenceUnit
  EntityManagerFactory factory;

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws ServletException, IOException
  {
//ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();

    java.util.List list = factory.createEntityManager().createQuery("select f from test_dept f;").getResultList();
    pw.println("<html><body bgcolor=silver text=green><table>");
    for (Object tdp : list)
    {
      pw.println("In The Loop");
      pw.println("<tr><td>" + ((TestDept) tdp).getDptnam() + "</td></tr>");
    }
    pw.println("</table>");
    pw.println("<font size=35><b>List created AdapChain</b></font>");
    pw.println("</body></html>");
  }
}
```

Comment: isnt the issue lies with factory?

Comment: Which one is line 28? Perhaps the `...factory.createEntityManager()...`? So perhaps the injection of your `@PersistenceUnit` doesn't work.

Comment: Which line is line 28 in ServletClient.java? Maybe your ` EntityManagerFactory` is not autowired.

Comment: may be `from test_dept f`, by the way, which line is line 28?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any version of Apache Tomcat supports injection of EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory objects out of the box.

You need to choose a server platform that supports more of the JavaEE specification.